# add _ # and & symbols  to preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/")

Tags: php, preg-replace, alphanumeric

Is it possible to take this preg_replace that limits to alphanumeric, and alter it so it also allows `_`, `&`, and `#`'s  (underscores, ampersands, and pound)?

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very easy...

```
preg_replace("/[^\w#& ]/")
```

The `\w` character class includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Thanks! also, does \w also include the semicolon if I wanted to include that as well?

Comment: @DankPiff No, it doesn't. You'd need to add it to the character class.

Comment: @alex what about adding a dash (-)?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_&#]/")`